# Running Puppeteer test with Travis on Create React App

Tags: reactjs, travis-ci, puppeteer

Puppeteer needs a server running to be able to run the tests. How do I `npm start` and `npm test` at the same time in travis?

My .travis.yml is

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"

cache:  
  directories:
    - "node_modules"

install:
  - npm install

script:
  - npm start
  - npm test
```

The build fails and says `The command "npm start" exited with 1.`

Comment: Don't use `npm start` on travis. You can start an express server on your global config / teardown. Take a look [here](https://github.com/yanivefraim/react-tdd-workshop) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this '&' symbol after  - npm start and sleep. 
Here is example:

```
script:
  - npm run start &
  - sleep 15
  - npm run test
```

also if you need to see in headless mode false add:

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```

P.s. I hope this will help you